# Reopening a closed pull request after rebasing its branch

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

My case is simple,
I created a branch say `foo` and pushed it to remote.
I created a pull request to merge it to the master branch.
After that I deleted remote branch on git, (I am using `git push origin --delete foo`).
After that I created some changes and did rebasing.
Then, I pushed this branch to remote having the same name `foo`.

Now, I want to be able to reopen the pull request but I am unable to do so, the reopen PR button is disabled.

What I want to achieve actually is to have clean commit history, and at the same time to be able to see for each pull request its own history.

The above mentioned process is available on the bitbucket.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you won't be able to create a new pull request with a branch having the same name as one used for a closed pull request.

[image: https://docs.github.com/assets/images/help/branches/branches-restore-deleted.png]

That is probably because, on GitHub, you can [restore a deleted branch from a closed PR](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/deleting-and-restoring-branches-in-a-pull-request#restoring-a-deleted-branch).
To avoid any collision with this possible restored branch, your new PR should have a different branch name.